# Weak solutions of incompressible/compressible fluids

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

While studying the weak solutions for incompressible or compressible fluids, they are mainly described by the system of partial differential equations known as Navier-Stokes equations. In most of the literature related to the named equations there are just two equations, namely; law of conservation of mass and momentum given as:

$$\rho_t+\mbox{div}(\rho u)=0 $$
$$ \partial_t(\rho u)+\operatorname{div}(\rho u \otimes u)-\mu\Delta u-\xi\nabla\operatorname{div} u+\nabla(P(\rho))=\rho f $$
while nothing about the energy equations. What is the reason that most of the authors do not including energy equation in their research work.
Looking forward for any of your helpful comment. Than you!
In specific when the authors are studying the weak solutions as in the work of Eduard Feireisl (On the Existence of Globally Defined Weak Solutions to the Navier–Stokes Equations )[1](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Egautam/research/201208-fluids-working-group/Feireisl_2001.pdf), and like many more

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you mean; **exactly what equation** are you referring to when you say energy equation'?

Comment: Your edit I don’t think addresses what Matthew is saying. But regardless, I suspect that your energy is derived from the rho and u, perhaps like rho u^2/2. if your PDE already uniquely determines rho and u then the energy is already determined. So there is no reason to add the energy to the system as a separate equation

Comment: @CalvinKhor as we that the fluid flow is modeled by foundational axioms of fluid dynamics are the conservation laws, specifically, conservation of mass, conservation of linear momentum, and conservation of energy. But in the above system of equations in the question, the first two conservations laws are in consideration but conservation of energy is not.

Comment: In the paper, equation 1.6 is telling you that energy is precisely the integral of rho times u^2 + some other thing. As I said, this is already determined by knowing u and rho, and formally you have energy conservation.

Comment: Ok Thank You, for your explanation